# jQuery.ajax() success callback have undefined parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making the following ajax call to a Wordpress file which handles WP user creation.

```
jQuery.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url, // Post URL
            data: userData, // Data
            context: self,
            success: self.handleUserResponse(),
            error: self.error
 })
```

Where `self` is the enclosing class object, and `handleUserResponse()` function which belongs to the enclosing class.

```
handleUserResponse: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(jqXHR);
}
```

The callback executes, and all three console.logs return `undefined`

Am I missing something?

Comment: No need to edit your posts with answer UPDATES. Simply accept the answer below (When you're able to), and the post will be marked as resolved.

Comment: handleUserResponse(insertdata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
success: self.handleUserResponse()
```

to

```
success: self.handleUserResponse
```

handleUserResponse() will result in the success callback parameters being set to undefined.